# Less-heavyweight alternative to GPT-2? (python)

Tags: windows, linux, open-source, python, artificial-intelligence

GPT-2 requires quite a large amount of processing power in order to be fast. I don't have a HUGE amount of processing power, and it seems a bit of overkill for what I want to do, which is get it to generate 1 or 2 small sentences based on some small texts I train it on.

Is there another, less powerful AI that I can use in Python which might suit these needs? It might not be as great as GPT-2, but in my use case, speed is more valuable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, the old way to do it was RNN

Comment: The old old way to do it is Markov chains, which are pretty simple to implement and if you google you can find various Python implemenations (e.g., [here](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify)).  Have you looked at such approaches?